# How to bind maven plugin execution to Snapshot versions of the project only?

Tags: git, maven

What I want to do is whenever I run "mvn install" command I need some plugin to be executed. Specifically, I need the sonar plugin to be executed which would check if there are any critical issues in the project. If there are, the build would fail.

However, I want this plugin to execute on the "development" branch only. The version of the project on development branch looks like this: 1.0.5-SNAPSHOT. The version of the project on master branch: 1.0.5

So, how do I run the plugin only on development branch? I figured, I could probably do this based on the version (snapshot only), but I'm not sure if it's possible

Comment: This is a job for a CI solution like Jenkins. There you can configure Sonar scans separately from your maven build.

Comment: The thing is, we would like to integrate it into the build, so that the build on CI and on local developer's machine is the same. As I said, we want to fail the maven build if critical sonar issues were found. It might be quite annoying for developers when the build on the local machine works, and fails on CI.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve this behaviour in the following way. First add build-helper-maven-plugin plugin to your build (on the beginning).

```
<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>bsh-property</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>bsh-property</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <properties>
              <property>skip.sonar</property>
            </properties>
            <source>skip.sonar = project.getVersion().endsWith("-SNAPSHOT") ? false : true;</source>
          </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The bsh-property goal executes beanshell script which defines skip.sonar property with true or false depending whether your version has snapshot at the end or not.

Then you can use skip property of sonar maven plugin.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
          ...
          <configuration>
            <skip>${skip.sonar}</skip>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not supported out of the box -- a plugin cannot automatically be triggered based on your project's `<version/>`. (Well, this is not exactly true, but you would have to be the author of the plugin and write your own logic for this, if you really wanted to; however this would only be applicable to your plugin).

What I would suggest would be to create Maven profile and trigger it via a command-line variable (`-DmyParam`), or by specifying the profile's name (`-PmyDevProfile`).

Have a look at the following links to gain a better understanding of Maven profiles:

- [The Sonatype Maven Book](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles.html)
- [Apache Maven: Introduction to Maven Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)
- [Apache Maven: Building for different environments](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html)

Comment: Yeah, that would work.. However, this way we would have to specify the profile every time we build the project, but I would like to have it integrated into the build, so that there is no need for developers to know about the profile name

Comment: I've been dealing with Maven since it's very early days. At the moment, there is no other way. This is what Maven profiles were designed for. Their inner workings aren't exactly the most convenient ones in quite a few common cases, but I don't think you really have a better option.